# Pass additional data into Zend_Paginator element

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-paginator

I have `Problems` model and each Problem has a relation with `Category` model so every Problem has exactly one Category. Here's my code which nicely returns the Problem and Category name to my view.

```
public function getPaginatorAdapter($category = null) {
        $select = $this->select();
        $select->setIntegrityCheck(false);
        $select->from(array('p' => 'problems', 'c' => 'categories'));
        $select->join(array('c' => 'categories'), 'c.id = p.category', array('c.category AS category_name'));
        $select->order('p.created DESC');
        if($category !== null) {
            $select->where('p.category = ?', $category);
        }

        return $adapter = new Zend_Paginator_Adapter_DbTableSelect($select);
```

Then I created additional `Tags` table and `ProblemsTags` many to many table so every Problem can have many Tags. My question is how to pass an array with Problem related Tags from ProblemsTags table to every element of paginator?

In plain PHP I would just iterate over all Problems and for each one I'd make database query for Tags. How to achieve this in Zend Framework?

Comment: You need to build a SQL select and pass it to the Paginator...so it already will contain all the data.

Comment: @dividebyzero Can you help with that? And wouldn't the resulting query have many rows (one for each tag) for each Problem instead of just one? I'm lost here

Comment: a lot of this depends on what your models look like. Personally I solved this type of problem by implementing a custom paginator adapter that relies on my mappers and creates my domain models. Then all the data that each model contains is always available with an accessor method.

Comment: Thanks @RockyFord I thought it could be done some other way around but once again I guess I need to extend base Zend classes.